# Enharmonic equivalent of C sharp in key of D major?

Tags: notation

I have been doing my music reading and something perplexed me. What is the enharmonic equivalent of C sharp in key of D major?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking here. C sharp is naturally in the key of D major. As Tims answer says, there are a few enharmonic equivalents, but there's no need to use them in the key of D. You'd just write a C, which is assumed to be a C sharp because that's denoted in the key signature.

Comment: @AJFaraday - one might need all sorts of enharmonic spellings, but not, as asked here, another enharmonic spelling of an existing diatonic note, as you say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key one's in doesn't affect the naming of enharmonic notes. The enharmonic of C# is Db in any key, although there won't be many instances of that note being named as Db whilst in the key of D.

Comment: The other option of B double sharp is equally unlikely in D major. Just because notes *can* have enharmonic equivalents doesn't mean they *should!*

Comment: "The other option" might be slightly misleading; theoretically, there's an infinite number of enharmonic equivalents for any note.

Comment: @11684 - an infinite number? I make it 3 for each, using x and bb where needed. There really is no need, technically, to go into ### or bbb territory - those enharmonic equivalents can usually be portrayed with sensible notation.

Comment: Well yes, that's why I inserted "theoretically", although there are some instances of triple flats and/or sharps. I only mentioned this because I think it would help the OP's understanding of enharmonic equivalents.

Comment: I can't think of any common situations where you would have a Db in D major but the first that comes to mind is a minor chord built on b6 (Bb minor), which would be quite a departure.  So basically yeah, there isn't much use for an enharmonic spelling of C# in D major unless you're doing some weird stuff.

Comment: Possibly - if there was a Bbo harmony in the piece (putting Bb as the root) would give cause to write Db. But that Bb ought to be written A#. Although I've read music where it's been written as Bb...

Comment: Yes, perhaps a common tone diminished chord on Bb that would resolve to the Bb major (bVI). That should provide a functionally appropriate spelling of Db.

Comment: @Basstickler - however, it could still resolve to the 'C#', and become V of D.

Comment: That's the nature of a CT Dim, it can resolve to 4 different chords and still be CT.  In the Bb version, it would properly be spelled with a Db but ultimately I think we would be just as likely to see it spelled with a C# because of the context of the tonal center, another quirk of diminished chords.